# About listen(), accept() in network socket programming(3-way handshaking)

Tags: c, sockets, networking

In network socket programming, I know what listen() and accept() do.

But, what I want to know is, in tcp, 3-way, where does the three-way handshaking occur.

Does listen() perform 3-way hand shaking, or is is it accept()?

I mean doing syn(client)   //     syn/ack(server)    //     ack(clinet) packet.

Comment: Neither.  `listen()` and `accept()` are not a direct interface to TCP (or any of the other supported protocols).  Certainly Danny_ds is right that `listen()` returns (or must be able to do) before any handshakes are performed, but that does not mean that the system waits for an `accept()` call before establishing connections.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Once the application has called `listen()`, the TCP stack will perform the 3-way handshake for any incoming connections. These connections are queued in the kernel, and `accept()` then retrieves the next connection from the queue and returns it.

There's a `backlog` argument to `listen`, and it specifies how large this queue should be (although I think some implementations ignore this, and use a limit built into the stack). When the queue is full, the stack will no longer perform the handshake for incoming connections; the clients should retry, and their connections will succeed when the queue has room for them.

It's done this way so that the client receives the `SYN/ACK` as quickly as possible in the normal case (when the backlog queue has room), so it doesn't have to retransmit the `SYN`.

Comment: If 3-way handshaking is not constructed(I mean client sends RST such like that), then connection is not queued in backlog queue? Accept() only returns new socket only if there are perfect 3-way handshaking in queue?

Comment: That's correct. As shown in the diagram in the other answer, `accept()` doesn't return until the 3-way handshake has been completed. He's only wrong about `accept()` triggering the 2nd step of the handshake.

Comment: @Barmar Are you sure that accept () system call doesn't trigger SYN + ACK at the server side ? This site says that accept() is reponsible for sending SYN + ACK https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-tcpsystemcalls/#connect

Comment: @Zephyr I'm certain I'm correct. Write a server that calls `listen()` but never calls `accept()`, then do a packet capture while the client connects to the port. I don't see where on that site it says that `accept()` sends the `SYN/ACK`.

Comment: It says: The server, after processing the SYN, sends a SYN ACK packet using the `tcp_output ()`, `ip_output ()`, and `if_output ()` sequence. Nothing about `accept()` triggering this.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are right. I somehow got confused thinking that accept is responsible for calling tcp_output() because they were in the same diagram.

Answer (score 0):

`listen()`, listens to requests that came to the server.

When a request is made (assume we use TCP, if you use UDP you will not use listen or accept its not connection oriented protocol like TCP) then it made the 3 way hand shake of TCP, if the server currently handling a request then the request gets moved to a queue.  The queue has a size you can specify, the max number of pending request is OS dependent, then there is another queue that accept function, take a request from each time listen, get called and return then return new socket to be used in this connection and the (address, port) of the request to `listen()`.